# Case class optional yet required field, for a Slick model

Tags: scala, slick

This might be bit chicken and egg question but here is the situation and I would like to hear your opinions.

there is a simple `case class` e.g.

```
case class Person(id:Option[Int],firstName:Option[String] ...)
```

Now Slick `Table` class looks as below

```
class Person(tag: Tag) extends Table[Person](tag, "person") {
def * = (id?, firstName) <> ((Person.apply _).tupled, Person.unapply)

def id = column[Int]("id", O.AutoInc, O.PrimaryKey)
```

Now reason why `id` was defined as `Option` in a `case class` is because this same `Person` class is used at other places in the app. e.g. serialize/deserialize `JSON` in a controller layer. Clearly `id` is not going to be passed in the incoming `JSON` when requests comes in to create a new record. At the same time having `Option` for `id` may be misleading when one is trying to retrieve `id` value from a case class since that's not really an optional field. IMO when I see `Option` type I think this may have `None` or `Some` but in this case it'll **always** have a value, from Slick/db, so defining it as `Option` is misleading.

I could define it as a `case class Person(id : SOME_CONST_NUM, firstName :Option[String] ..)` so whenever you pass that to Slick for insert, Slick will insert a PK value. Retrieve data from `Person` you always do `Person.id` and get value which Slick gave you back. Usage wise this is clear and more appropriate. But then having this hardcoded default `SOME_CONST_NUM` is ugly and code smell.

How would you define `id` field in this scenario?

Comment: Have you tried to fill field with a default value? (just put values (which you don't need to fill) to the end of class definition): `case class Person(firstName: Option[String], ..., id: Option[Int] = None)` ; then you can create an instance of this class: `Person("name", ... here some values but without id)` so you even don't need to fill it.

Comment: @DaunnC That precisely what I am trying to avoid of having a `id:Option[Int] = None` that gives an impression that `id` is optional field, which it is for for the first time used in JSON serializer, from controller, but Slick will insert a value in it. Subsequently when you query you'll always have a value in that field being a PK so if API user has to treat `id` as `Option` and do patten match or getOrElse, IMO it's wrong because it's not an `optional` field. Hope I am making sense here.

Comment: hm, I see now what are you trying. Have no idea how you can deal with it without this monad, but it is not as ugly as hardcoded value of id.

Comment: Probably one way would be to define a `trait Human` which has all the fields like name etc and then have two case classes, one for slick (with the non optional id) and one for your json operations. As you said having to query by id with an option is very misleading, anyway I'm not sure this is the best way.